# Microsoft Botframework channel messenger not working in development mode

Tags: botframework, messenger

I need enable channel messenger for botframework.
i make follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook#enable-messenger

exclude "submit for review". i want test before submit review.

```
Until an app is published, it is in Development Mode. Plugin and API functionality will only work for admins, developers, and testers.
```

i am administrator for app & that page.
i try chat but bot not working.

**Env info:**
Facebook API version: 2.12
Bot framework ver: 3.14
And i has migrated to azure bot service.

**My bot screenshots:**

[Facebook app & web hook setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95q5z.png)

[Bot setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nEUY.png)

[Channel status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57BCx.png)

[Skype channel status is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFjrS.png)

[In messenger bot not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0chA9.png)

Any one can help me ?

Thank in advance!

Comment: With just this input it will be difficult for us to help. Check again every step

Comment: thanks.
i has tried again, from beginning but still same.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved!**

My problem is: i detected a problem about my account "Your free credit has expired after i create new bot service.
then i fix above issue, and bot worked.

Hope Azure service will show alert when create new channel for trial program.

Answer (score 0):

If you just channel messenger for botframework about yesterday, so I think that your issues relate to my issues:

[403 forbidden with POST request on https://facebook.botframework.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937801/403-forbidden-with-post-request-on-https-facebook-botframework-com)

My facebook channels bot framework worked well about 6 months till 2018, 19 April. All request suddendly response 403 forbidden.

And I am trying to find any document which mentioned to  any change or update API from microsoft bot server at 2018, 19 April.

Comment: i see, so i was created bot at time that occurs error.
Thank for your information. i will push your issue too.

Comment: Hi @Tidusvn05,

The issue has solved and my facebook channel at azure bot service  up again. Think that you can try again with your new bot.

Comment: i try many times but  still same. i got error: Failed to validate incoming Facebook message. Make sure your FacebookAppSecret is entered correctly. i sure that App secret same with facebook channel setting.

Answer (score 0):

The following is some steps for facebook set up which help me on the succcess:

step1 - Get app_id and app_secret

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCdKH.jpg

step2 - Webhooks for page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ve8u.jpg

step3 - Webhooks for page - enter microsoft bot service callback and verify token

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX2qR.png

step 4- Messenger setting - subscribe page and get page access_token

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwwj4.jpg

step 5 - Get page_id at facebook page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL78m.jpg

Comment: thanks for your comment. i sure that my steps same your steps.
- i try many time, but bot still don't response. i check in bot log, don't have access request from outside. maybe problem at bot service. 

- I create other bot using sample of facebook is ok. then i change callback url and verify token to botframework url and verify again => bot still not working. 
- Other channels: skype, slack still working good. i don't understand what the current problem for facebook channel ? connect guide  similar simple but not.

Comment: i has fixed my problem, a problem related to trial program. thank for your support again !