# 403 forbidden with POST request on https://facebook.botframework.com

Tags: botframework

Every POST request to the following API get 403 forbidden :

https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/{{conversation_id}}/activities
https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/{{bot_name}} ; which is webhook url registered at facebook bot

Noted :

- Bot framework already is Bot Service Azure before 2018 March 31
- Facebook channel at Bot Service Azura worked well about 6 months. And these issues just happens from 2018, 19th April
- Tested facebook bot worked well with my own webhook url
- Tested skype channel at Bot Service Azura still worked well.
- All configure of facebook channel at Bot Service Azure are right.

Comment: i also got issue when create new bot. maybe the problem is same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916935/microsoft-botframework-channel-messenger-not-working-in-development-mode

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Comment: The facebook channel of bot service azure worked  again at 2018 April 23. I think that the issue has solved by the bot service developers.

Answer (score 0):

After three days failed and there is no facebook message come to my system via Bot Service Azure. Finally, my Facebook channel at Bot Service Azure is up again at 2018 April 23. The issues solved.